# Storing fetched data in parent component, what is standard React practice?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, fetch

What is common practice for storing data in a parent component to be passed to child components in React? For example:

```
export default class Main extends Component{
    async componentWillMount(){
         let data = await fetch(some data);
    }
}
```

Where should the 'let data' be stored if I plan on passing it to child components? I don't want to put it into a state, because I feel that's used only for when you need to re-render. Also is the above the correct way to fetch data? Let's say I just logged in and as I'm redirecting to this Main class I want it to fetch the data then render. What is standard practice?

Answer (score 1):

You **should** want to put it into the state. Of course, it will rerender when state changes, thanks to this your child component is updated when it gets new props. Other than that you can't update your child component. This is the right way of doing this.

You can fetch the data in `componentDidMount` since `componentWillMount` will be deprecated in the future releases (v17). So, you fetch data there than set your state:

```
export default class Main extends Component{
    async componentDidMount(){
         let data = await fetch(some data);
         this.setState({data: some data});
    }
}
```